# serializing xml tags to c# dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an api that returns xml in the following form

```
<root>
<sometag>somevalue</sometag>
<sometag>somevalue</sometag>
<Rights>
    <admin>true</admin>
    <admin_employees>true</admin_employees>
    <admin_inventory>true</admin_inventory>
    <admin_purchases>true</admin_purchases>
    <admin_shops>true</admin_shops>
    <admin_void_sale>true</admin_void_sale>
</Rights>
</root>
```

I'm using System.Xml.Serialization and am having trouble getting the "Rights" section to serialize without strongly typing the entire thing as its only used once.

Ideally, I would like to have it serialize to a dictionary with the tag name being the key. How would I achieve this? or is there another method that would work better?

hoping for a usage similar to `if(Rights["admin"]) ...`

Comment: you can use [*LinqToXml*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) to achieve this.

Comment: can you please also post the code you are using to deserialize the xml?

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentioned the use of XmlSerializer to deserialize the content,

to stick with it, here is another solution using XmlSerializer.Deserialize() to help you if you already have a class for the entire root object but don't want to type properties for every flag in the Rights collection.

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class RootObject
{
    // . . . other properties
    // . . . if you have them
    // . . . and just don't put here anything
    // . . . if you don't need them
    public XmlElementDictionary<bool> Rights { get; set; }
}
```

If the XML you've received has exactly the same format as you put in your question, the following will parse the Rights elements into a dictionary. By implementing IXmlSerializable, we tell the serialization system that we want to serialize/deserialize this type ourselves.

Please note that the writing and schema support is not implemented.

```
public class XmlElementDictionary<TValue> : Dictionary<string, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
{
    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        string startElementName = reader.Name;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string keyName = reader.Name;
            if (keyName == startElementName) break;
            reader.Read(); // Read element value
            base.Add(keyName, (TValue)Convert.ChangeType(reader.Value, typeof(TValue)));
            reader.Read(); // Read end element

        }
    }

    System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

The generic implementation makes this re-usable for other types. The reading logic can be improved to check for any attributes (fails now if there are attributes, but should give you a clear idea how to read just an element and its inner text)

Here is how to use it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RootObject rootObject = 
        (RootObject)new XmlSerializer
            (typeof(RootObject)).Deserialize(new StringReader(XML));

    if(rootObject.Rights["admin"])
    {
        . . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: oh that looks perfect, will give it a try in a bit!

Answer (score 0):

See following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, Boolean> dict = doc.Descendants("Rights").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (Boolean)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```